# Insert collection data into a table using a procedure (kindly read the question for detailed explanation)

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, procedure, bulk-collect

I would like to insert the collection from the out parameter of a different proc into a table using a procedure.
Let me give u the code to explain clearly.

```
Create type t1 is object
   Name varchar2 (10),
    Address varchar2 (50),
    Pin number);

create type t is table of t1;

create procedure PS1 (P1 out t)
Is 
 TE t := t();
 Begin
  Te.extend();
 Select t1(name, address,pin) bulk 
 collect into TE
 From table1;
-- note: table1 has same table structure as object t1;
End;
```

Now I have two requirements. For testing purpose, i would like to print one of the data in the collection.

```
 Declare
 A t := t();
 Begin
 a.extend ();
 PS1(a);
 DBMS.output.put_line(a(1).pin);
 -- after completing this a validation will check if the 
 -- pin has null values.
   If a(1).pin is not null
   Then 
    Insert into t2  values ( 
      a(1).name, a(1).address, b 
      a(1).pin);
    End if;
   --note: table t2 is also of the same structure of object t1;
    End;
```

Here my code is giving an error as reference to uninitialised collection. But as you can see, i have initialised the collection in declaration itself.

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM table1;

NAME       ADDRESS              PIN
---------- ------------- ----------
CLARK      NEW YORK            7782
KING       NEW YORK            7839
MILLER     NEW YORK            7934
```

`t2` is empty, but has the same structure as `table1`:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t2
  2  AS
  3     SELECT *
  4       FROM table1
  5      WHERE 1 = 2;

Table created.
```

Types:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t1 IS OBJECT
  2  (
  3     name VARCHAR2 (10),
  4     address VARCHAR2 (50),
  5     pin NUMBER
  6  );
  7  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t IS TABLE OF t1;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Procedure (note differences; you don't have to initialize nor extend anything. Also, in your code, you're populating `te` but never returned anything because `out` parameter's name is `p1`, not `te`):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ps1 (p1 OUT t)
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4     SELECT t1 (name, address, pin)
  5       BULK COLLECT INTO p1
  6       FROM table1;
  7  END;
  8  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     a  t;
  3  BEGIN
  4     ps1 (a);
  5
  6     FOR i IN a.FIRST .. a.LAST
  7     LOOP
  8        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
  9           a (i).name || ', ' || a (i).address || ', ' || a (i).pin);
 10
 11        IF a (i).pin IS NOT NULL
 12        THEN
 13           INSERT INTO t2 (name, address, pin)
 14                VALUES (a (i).name, a (i).address, a (i).pin);
 15        END IF;
 16     END LOOP;
 17  END;
 18  /
CLARK, NEW YORK, 7782
KING, NEW YORK, 7839
MILLER, NEW YORK, 7934

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

`t2` table's contents:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t2;

NAME       ADDRESS              PIN
---------- ------------- ----------
CLARK      NEW YORK            7782
KING       NEW YORK            7839
MILLER     NEW YORK            7934

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.. one quick doubt in this.  "you don't have to initialize nor extend anything". But nested table is dense in nature, right? Is there any reason not to extend/initialise it ? Or this would change based on scenario ?

Comment: When you use bulk collect (which is what procedure PS1 does), the collection is populated densely (and index starts with 1).

Comment: Thanks for the response.. And sorry for asking you again since I'm unable to get a clear view on this topic. Leave about the question. In general, nested tables are dense in nature and requires initialisation as per my understanding. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong. Now PS1 does use nested table but without initialisation.. same goes with the anonymous block.. how is this working?  Or there is no need to initialize/extend the nested table as in associative array.. ?

Comment: Nested tables and varrays have to be initialized, while associative arrays don't have to. But, if you use BULK COLLECT, Oracle **implicitly** initializes and extends your nested table.